# Cannot Submit Braintree with Validation Error

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, braintree

I was trying to submit the form payment form that I implemented. But in the submission process some parts of the codes are not working as expected, the form cannot be validated.

Previously the validation codes were in the same JS file as the codes to initialise the fields, but I separated due to the submit action was done in a JS file rather than a normal submit in JSP/HTML.

Here is what I put into the submit action:

```
function submitContinue()
{

    $('#paymentDetailsForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {

          hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
            if (tokenizeErr) {
              console.error(tokenizeErr);
              // Display tokenization error message as per application's standard in here.
              return;
            }
               debugger;
            console.log('Got a nonce: ' + payload.nonce);
            $('#ajaxModalText').text('Got Payment Method Nonce: ' + payload.nonce);
                debugger;
            // Capture and store the payment method nonce into our hidden HTML input field
            $('#paymentMethodNonce').val(payload.nonce);

            // Now submit the form ... which will submit with value of the hidden HTML input field for the payment method nonce
            $.post( "/quotes/new_quote_payment_details", $( "#paymentdetails-Form" ).serialize() )
              .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

              })
              .done(function( data ) {

              });
          });
        }
      });

    document.querySelector('input[name="paymentMethodNonce"]').value = payload.nonce;


    //Submits ownership details form
    if(checkMandatories())
    {
        $j("#btn-get").prop("disabled", true);

        document.forms.paymentDetailsForm.method="post";
        document.forms.paymentDetailsForm.action = appContextPath + "/quotes/new_quote_payment_details";
        var target = document.getElementById('activity');

        //Center the spinner div
        $j("#activity").position({
            of: $j(window)
        });


        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        document.forms.paymentDetailsForm.submit();
    }


}
```

I thought the form would be submitted and a Payment Method Nonce would be generated and saved into a hidden field that I've setup within the JSP. Instead the error that I received was

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of null
```

Comment: I've replaced     $('#paymentDetailsForm').validate
( submitHandler: function(form) {

    Into     form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();

Now the error message that I get is Uncaught ReferenceError: payload is not defined

Comment: Have you set `var submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');` ?
And earlier in your code are you calling `braintree.client.create` and `braintree.hostedFields.create`?
_Disclaimer: I work for Braintree. Please reach out to_ **support@braintreepayments.com** _with further questions._

Comment: Yes I have called those in a seperate JS file called Braintree.js, the codes that I placed above is located in another JS file called submit.js, as the current system submit action is using JS. Because when I placed the codes above into Braintree.js its executing as soon as I load the page.